# My emails are being sent to spam and I want to switch domain to resolve. Should I set up an alias or start from scratch?

Tags: domains

I have a .com domain which was hacked around 1 year ago. This caused the domain to be blacklisted and I've had a problem with email going to spam ever since.

I have since used tools like Sucuri to help get our domain off the blacklists. However, I still get reports from my recipients saying my emails are going to spam. I used MxToolbox to help identify missing DKIM and DMARC records which I've now added and am waiting to see if this will make a change.

However, I also own a .agency domain and I'm tempted to set up new email addresses on this domain and just stop using the .com.

I use Gsuite to manage my email and I'm aware I can create an alias so that I can preserve my current inboxes, but I'm wondering if I do this then will the .agency inherit the spam records of the .com? Is it just better to create a new Gsuite account instead of an alias, even though that would mean I would have separate inboxes?

Comment: Have you checked your domain at https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/email_rep?  Sometimes a simple change of IP address for your server will solve the problem, as long as the cause of the spam has been handled or you'll just end up listed again.

Comment: If you're able to ask some of your reporters to send you the details of the headers of the recieved emails that might also tell you where the problem lies. It might be content based rather than domain for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also added the appropriate SPF records? (Although if you are using GSuite to manage your email, then I would assume you will have already done this?)

I don't see how the `.agency` domain would *inherit* the "spam records" of the `.com`? Unless it was the IP that is blacklisted, but if you are using GSuite that is going to be difficult to change. (But is GSuite limited in the number of IPs it uses? And to blacklist the GSuite IPs would be silly, but some blacklists do not discriminate.)

There should be no difference between configuring the domain as an "alias" and using an entirely new GSuite account. I'm pretty sure that whatever spam-check is causing your email to be identified as spam is not coming from Google/GSuite.

> I still get reports from my recipients saying my emails are going to spam.

Different email providers / ISPs use different mechanisms/blacklists to catch spam.  To identify where exactly the email is being flagged you may need to find the specific users / email providers that are flagging your email and work backwards. Are these users using additional email filtering / anti-virus on their machines?

Comment: SPF was also already in place, yes. I'll do some extra questioning as additional antivirus might be in place. Based on this though I probably will set up an alias. Thanks